# UWP Printing from Windows app directly without bringing Print Dialog

Tags: c#, printing, uwp

1. Does POS printer just support Epson printers? (related to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt426652)
2. How to send a document directly to the printer without showing Print Dialog?

Comment: Hamed, please note that the edit you accepted changed the question, which is unfair on Grace (an answerer below) as he has no way of telling that you've modified the question in order to modify the answer... and he shouldn't be obliged to modify the answer anyway. **If you have a new question, ask it as a new question rather than changing an existing question to fit...**

Comment: Please read the question,first! that's related to @Hamed's questions!!

Comment: @Nasser, I can see your question now, thanks to Seb. For your last question, please refer to the official sample in my answer, there are js projects in both samples. Next time please ask a new question.

Comment: How to use Epson ESC/POS with formatting in UWP App https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/epson-esc-pos-with-formatting

Comment: There should be something like await Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.PrintAsync();

Answer (score 5):

> ESC/POS is a command system created by Epson used across a wide range of POS printer systems, aimed at avoiding incompatible command sets by providing universal applicability. Most modern printers support ESC/POS.

So, for your first question, I think the answer is no. This [POS printer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt426652.aspx) API can be used for all the printers which support ESC/POS. Please refer to [Epson ESC/POS with formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt592875.aspx).

For your second question, using `POS printer` API, you can print without a Print Dialog.

But I assume, what you want is [Windows.Graphics.Printing namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.printing.aspx). For this printing in a UWP app, the Print Preview UI must be shown to guide user complete the printing operation.

You can refer to the official [POS printer sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PosPrinter) and [Printing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing).

**Update 2/1/2016:**

> using POS printer API, you can print without a Print Dialog.

@Seb, this is my personal conclusion, the official document of POS printer doesn't mention anything about a UI dialog.

But in the short sample in the document and official sample, when we print with a pos device, we create a print job at first, then call the [PrintLine(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn952340.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) method with the content which we want to print, at last, we execute it/them with [ExecuteAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.pointofservice.receiptprintjob.executeasync.aspx) method, this method

> Runs the print job on the receipt printer station asynchronously.

In this process, we don't show any dialog unlike in the normal printing. In the normal printing, when we want to print a document from our app, we call [ShowPrintUIAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.printing.printmanager.showprintuiasync.aspx) method, this method will show a dialog to provide guidance for users to help them complete a printing-related oricess.

@Hamed, this Pos printer API can't support those device without ESC/POS, I'm not sure if it possible to send commands to your printer and get response from it  through serial port, I think you may read the develop document of your printer.

Comment: This answer appears to draw from credible and/or official sources to support your answer to the first question, which fulfills 50% of the criteria for the bounty offered. However, I couldn't find anything supporting this: "For your second question, using `POS printer` API, you can print without a Print Dialog." Can you support this with a quote from the documentation, or a reference to some code within a specific sample?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I want to know how to use without ESC/POS. because I'm using kiosk printer and that doesn't support ESC/POS. Waiting for your answer.

Comment: @Seb, thank you seb, please see the update in my answer.

Comment: Did you mean "process" instead of "oricess"?

Comment: @Seb, maybe, I also understand it as "process". It is the sentence in the official document, I think it is a spelling error.