# Hide print dialog box in UWP apps

Tags: .net, printing, uwp

Trying to print from a UWP app, but when the user clicks a button we'd like to skip the print dialog and just print the output. Its in a controlled environment and the user doesn't need to make any changes for printing.

Comment: Can we see some code? How is it that you are printing?

Comment: To my knowledge still not possible with the out of the box printing api's in UWP

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029821/uwp-printing-from-windows-app-directly-without-bringing-print-dialog