# Print raw data in UWP

Tags: printing, uwp, windows-store-apps

I'm developing an app in UWP. I need to send to my printer a RAW string (or file) and get that printed. I succed in using the old `RawPrinterHelper` from [here](https://github.com/andyyou/SendToPrinter/blob/master/Printer/RawPrinterHelper.cs).

I have some problems verifiyng the app using the Windows App Certification Kit. 
I get errors like this one :

> API ClosePrinter in winspool.drv is not supported for this application type. MyApp.dll calls this API.

I think that `DllImport()` in `RawPrinterHelper` is wrong.

Is there a way to use a diffent `RawPrinterHelper` or bypass the Windows App Certification Kit in some way?

P.S. I need to publish the app on the Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already run the WACK test with the release build, then as the error described there are APIs not supported for the windows store app. More details please reference [Supported API test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-app-certification-kit-tests#supported-api-test).

> Is there a way to use a diffent RawPrinterHelper or bypass the Windows App Certification Kit in some way

For print relative features in windows store app, please follow [this tutorial](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/printing-and-scanning) and  the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing). This provide alternatives to the windows print relative APIs. Details please reference [Printing and documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/alternatives-to-windows-apis-uwp#printing-and-documents) section of [Alternatives to Windows APIs in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/alternatives-to-windows-apis-uwp).

If you want the print feature with no print dialog you may reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029821/uwp-printing-from-windows-app-directly-without-bringing-print-dialog).